# Get the 2d image that was used to render a specific face in the 3D model

Tags: blender, meshlab

I have a 3d cube model that is rendered with multiple images similar to [[this]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvGAM_Bg-AE%20this) tutorial. 
When I click on a point in the 3d model I want to get the image that corresponds to the face of the selected point. 
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are looking for. Is your question: when I click on a point in the Meshlab 3d model I want to get the texture that corresponds to the face of the selected point.

Comment: When I click a point in the Meshlab 3d model I want to get the **image file name** that was used to create the texture.
I basically want to reverse engineer and get the corresponding image based on the vertex selection.
Or is it the case, that once the 3d model is renderred, the information about the original images that were used in the rendering is lost, and only the final rendered texture is left in the 3d model file?